# Chrome 'backspace key navigation re-enable' question dupe closure should probably be the other way around

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, exact-duplicates

[How can I re-enable backspace navigation in Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/1084337/how-can-i-re-enable-backspace-navigation-in-chrome) (2016-06-04, 6006+ views) is currently closed as a duplicate of [Re-enabling backspace as "go back" in recent Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/1111519/re-enabling-backspace-as-go-back-in-recent-chrome) (2016-08-09, 630+ views).

This is despite the former question being posted first, has more research info/effort, has more views, and has more upvotes on the question and its answers. It is clearly deemed better by the community seeing that the latter question has currently zero votes.

I'm thinking the dupe closure should be the other way around. (That, or a merge.) This is also to discourage lower quality duplicate questions in the future.

Comment: It only has more views because it was tweeted.  It being tweeted and thus more views (which leads to more votes) isn't a good reason to switch the duplicate flags around.  If anything the questions should be merged, since I partially agree, the answer the quotes the purpose of the add-on is a higher quality, but the question isn't, so its a complete wash.

Comment: @Ramhound I'd agree with merging. What made you say that the later-posted question was higher in quality? The first-posted question has more research info/effort in it. Tweeted or otherwise, the first question is clearly deemed better by the community, seeing that the later question has currently zero votes. Also, to discourage lower quality duplicates in the future, I believe we should mark the older question as the original.

Comment: I make specific reference to the reason I think the answer, with the quoted text, is higher quality.  The question quality is about netural (IMO), the fact one was tweeted, has not effect on my opionion on the quality of the question.

Comment: I would go with galacticninja on this one.  I think the older question is clearer, has more answers that people found useful, and the answers are better quality.  The answers on the newer question are little more than links, including one covered better in the older question.  Also, two of the answers on the older question do not require browser extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question [How can I re-enable backspace navigation in Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/1084337/how-can-i-re-enable-backspace-navigation-in-chrome) has been reopened and the newer question has been marked as duplicate and merged into the older one since the older question has higher quality posts